# Is there any way to cancel Panels' overlay edit windows?

Tags: panels, performance, modal-dialogs

I don't want to edit Panel panes via overlay edit-windows and therefore I tried to disable the core "Overlay" module at `admin/modules` but it seems to effect everything except the overlay of the Panels module.

Note: The reason I want to disable Panels' overlay is because it's slow to me (especially in Dev periods when I disable cache, and that it sometimes stuck and loads "Forever")... Besides, it cannot be open in a new tab, as I would prefer.

Do you know how to disable it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some research and looked into Panels 3 code so far I don't see any nojs fallbacks. You can also check if there are fallbacks when you try to disable Javascript in the browser.

This may not be the answer on how to disable Panels modals but you may increase PHP, MySQL and or Apache settings and increase memory to your local host.

Comment: Node.JS? Fallbacks?...

Comment: No, I meant the AJAX Graceful Degradation coding way of coding (https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example%21ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc/group/ajax_degradation_example/7) where code checks if JS is off and if it is then it will give you a normal page where it doesn't need and JS for it to run like the modal popup.